# Insert .css into HTML on omeka

Tags: html, css, omeka

Hi I am working on building a webpage using omeka. I am working in a simple page that automatically creates HTML code. It generates this code based on the theme you select. The site has the ability to edit the css through an extension of the site. However, with the theme that was desided for the site you cannot use the css editor to format the page. You have the ability to add html short codes. I would really like to reformat the text and the background for this page in particular without changing the settings for the rest of the site. A way to do that is by inserting css code into the html. The problem is I am not sure where to insert the code at.

Here is an example:

[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg4Yf.jpg)
(sorry if images are poor quality)
Where would I insert the suggested css

When I do this it changes either the alignment or text color but it will not do both. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? I am fairly new to coding and most of my expierence is working with css not html.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="text-align:justify; color:blue;"></p>
```

According to your example, you're adding another style attribute inside of your p tag. That will not work. You need to separate your styles with a semicolon.